# iphone how can i add the events in the calendar?

Tags: iphone, ios5, calendar, xcode4.2

I am trying to  make a calendar and  view the calendar in which i  can create ,edit or delete the events on tap of the button , the events created should be viewed weekly I have tried out kal ,tapku library  Calendar but could not find appropriate.Are there any link or code that could help me out with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>
#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>

EKEventViewController *detailViewController;
EKEventStore *eventStore;
eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init]; 
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore]; 
event.title = @"Test Event"; 
event.startDate = copyofnextappdt; 
event.endDate = copyofnextappdt;
[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```